# How do I retrieve only the domain name in SQLite?

Tags: regex, sqlite, query-string

My table has got a column with strings like this :

```
"http://news.yahoo.com/whats-super-tuesday-419-gop-delegates-130610354.html"
"http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/05/us/politics/republican-party-moves-toward-romney-ahead-of-super-tuesday.html?_r=1&hp"
"http://www.washingtonpost.com/2010/07/08/AB582vC_page.html"
```

I would like to to get this column :

```
"http://news.yahoo.com/"
"http://www.nytimes.com/"
"http://www.washingtonpost.com/"
```

How do I get there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Sorry but I don't find the answer in the post you point to : I don't want to find a query string but to replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is C# code and uses .Net regular expressions, but you can tweak as necessary if your regex flavor is a little different:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex rx = new Regex( "\"(http://.*?/)(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
string rxReplace = "\"$1\"";

string input = "http://foo.com/fubar.html";

// Produces "http://foo.com/"
string output = rx.Replace( input, rxReplace );
```