# Return rows where first character is non-alpha

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like, alphanumeric

I'm trying to retrieve all columns that start with any non alpha characters in SQlite but can't seem to get it working. I've currently got this code, but it returns every row:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE TestNames NOT LIKE '[A-z]%'
```

Is there a way to retrieve all rows where the first character of TestNames are not part of the alphabet?

Comment: Just non-alpha, so it should return anything beginning with `1,2,_, etc..`)

Comment: That `[]` range syntax is SQL Server. [Can't see any indication that SQLLite supports it in the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Comment: Thanks Martin, that might be the issue. My SQL skills aren't all that great, but is there an alternative method of performing something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you going first character only?

```
select * from TestTable WHERE substr(TestNames,1) NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

The substr function (can also be called as left() in some SQL languages) will help isolate the first char in the string for you.

edit:
Maybe substr(TestNames,1,1) in sqllite, I don't have a ready instance to test the syntax there on.

Added:

```
select * from TestTable WHERE Upper(substr(TestNames,1,1)) NOT in ('A','B','C','D','E',....)
```

Doesn't seem optimal, but functionally will work.   Unsure what char commands there are to do a range of letters in SQLlite.

I used 'upper' to make it so you don't need to do lower case letters in the not in statement...kinda hope SQLlite knows what that is.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still returning every row (same as if I did `select * from TestTable`)

Comment: Does select substr(TestNames,1) from testable return just the first char for you?   If it does, we just need to alter the not like statement to something more SQLLite friendly.

Comment: `substr(TestNames,1,1)` works fine so it seems that the `not like` statement is the issue.

Comment: Wanna do this the silly way?   

select * from TestTable WHERE upper(substr(TestNames,1,1)) NOT IN ('A','B','C'...)

Yes, I am suggesting you do a not in and put each letter in individually.  Upper means it's always upper case and you won't need to worry about lower case.   I'm not sure if there is any other method in SQLlite to do a char range.  Put into the answer for you.

Comment: I'll use this suggestion for now and mark it as answer tomorrow if nothing else comes up in between. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know, definitely not the prettiest solution I've come with up on stack overflow.

Comment: I'll go with this solution. Not any real problems performance wise (only 26 characters) so should suffice. Thanks again.

Comment: heres the full string to save time for others.   select * from TestTable WHERE Upper(substr(TestNames,1,1)) NOT in ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H', 'I', 'J','K','L','M','N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R','S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X','Y', 'Z'

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE TestNames NOT LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: That's also returning everything. Is this because of Sqlite's lack of built in regex?

Comment: sqlite3 supports regex [     WHERE fld REGEXP <regex>]    should work.. whats urs?

Comment: sqlite3, but when I use that, I get `no such function: REGEXP`. That function doesn't work out the box and I've had troubles trying to get it working. Am hoping to avoid regex for this type of call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: i belive regexp is not supported out of the box! http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: There may be a typo here. We are looking for all nonalpha characters, but this will return all alpha characters since the two nots here cancel each other out

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM NC_CRIT_ATTACH WHERE substring(FILENAME,1,1) NOT LIKE '[A-z]%';
SHOULD be a little faster as it is
A) First getting all of the data from the first column only, then scanning it.
B) Still a full-table scan unless you index this column.

Comment: It returns all rows. Not sure if this is related to SQLite's lack of regex?