# SQLAlchemy: What expression to put in "like" to select from a table where some string column does not start with a letter of the alphabet?

Tags: python, regex, sqlalchemy

I have a database table called `shop`. Every `shop` has a `string` `title`.

I'm now trying to get all the shops that has a title that does not start with an English alphabet character.

So now I'm doing something like:

```
shops = db.query(Shop)\
        .filter(Shop.title.like('SOME_EXPRESSION'))\
        .all()
```

May I know what to choose for `SOME_EXPRESSION` please? Do I need a regular expression here? Or some other expression?

From what I know, if I put `A%` there, it is getting all shops with `title` that starts with `A`.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196538/return-rows-where-first-character-is-non-alpha) is a question with answers that show ways to do this in SQL. Once you know that, you can convert the SQL to SQLAlchemy.