# SQL Query to get all names having (whole or part of) searched name

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using sqlite right now and wants to know if any SQL query exists to get all the names having searched name as whole or some part of name. I have saved all names in one column i.e. "name" column and wants to get like if I have saved "abc", "xyz" and "abc xyz" as names and searched abc then it should give results like: "abc" and "abc xyz" and similar for for other names....

Answer (score 3):

If the search term can be in any part of the `name` column, surround your search term with wildcard characters ('%') and use the `LIKE` operator:

```
WHERE
    name LIKE '%abc%'
```

If you want all `name`s that **start** with "abc":

```
WHERE
    name LIKE 'abc%'
```

Or all `name`s that **end** with "abc":

```
WHERE
    name LIKE '%abc'
```

Comment: @HusnainIqbal: I see you're new here; if an answer helped you, vote it up. If an answer provided you with a solution, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark outline to the left of it. You can only accept one, so pick which one you feel is best.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Like operator for this situation

```
 SELECT  * 
    FROM table  
    WHERE Name  LIKE '%abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite3 [supports regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query), merely need to put `where name REGEXP 'abc'` as your where clause. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

```
"abc", "xyz" and "abc xyz" as names
search by "abc" 
results like: "abc" and "abc xyz"
```

You should use `field like "abc%"`