# Sql query for pattern search using wildcard

Tags: sql, search, wildcard

I am developing an iphone app which has its backend in Sqlite. I want to search a pattern from the db table. I used the following query for that

```
SELECT roman,walpha FROM gurbani where walpha LIKE 'rm rs% p%'
```

My requirement is the results should contain first word 'rm', second word starting with 'rs' and the third word must start with 'p'.

The following is a screen shot of the result of my sql query

[image]

Here in my results the lines in walpha 3,6 and 7 are wrong, as I want the third word to be starting with the letter'p'. This is because of the use of 'rs%' in the sql query. So I tried another query as follows:

```
SELECT roman,walpha FROM gurbani where walpha LIKE 'rm rs p%'
```

But this results only the 4th line in the above screenshot. I am new in Sql. Is there any other method for search my pattern ?

Comment: You could use an appropriate regular expression for your query. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Answer (score -1):

select roman,walpha from gurbani where walpha like 'rm%rs%p%'

try this it should definitely work for your requirement.

Comment: No..This cannot be done. While using wildcars it will not ensure the positions of the words, that means any words or characters can be there in the '%'