# How to do NOT in LIKE query in SQLite?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
    id      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    key     VARCHAR,
    value   VARCHAR
)

id       key     value
1        Hi      ABCDE/FGHI
2        Hi      DFGRT
3        Hi      FSEHU/
```

Pre-existing library function (edited for clarity):

```
char* Foo_getId(char *value){
    char *query = "SELECT id FROM Foo WHERE value LIKE ?";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, query, strlen(query), &statement, NULL);
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, value, strlen(value), SQLITE_STATIC);
    rc = sqlite3_step(statement);
    return strdup((char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0));
}
```

My function:

```
char *getFooIdFromValueWithoutSlash(){
    return Foo_getId("WHAT GOES HERE???");
}
```

How do create a LIKE query such that it will match any value which does not contain a '/'?

E.g. `SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE value LIKE '%!/%'`

Note: the reason I am trying to do this is that I am interfacing with someone elses code of which I can only pass the value placed after the like.

Comment: You can't do what you're asking. You can't negate a `LIKE` using only the value provided after it; that's not how `LIKE` works. You can negate it by modifying the query to use `NOT LIKE`, but you have to modify the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct a `LIKE` pattern that behaves the same as a `NOT LIKE` pattern; the only special characters are `%` and `_`.

That someone else's code is just not capable of doing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE value NOT LIKE '%/%'
```

Comment: That would be great, but is there an equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`? As I said, I cant change the query, I can only pass in the argument passed in for the LIKE.

Comment: @chacham15 For that you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: @chacham15 Do you want to use a `LIKE` expression or a regular expression? Please edit your question to clarify this!