# LIKE with word boundary and wildcard in SQL or AREL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

How can I create an arel query, or even straight sql query, that returns a search term within a string, but only when the term is a single word (and not part of another word).

As seen below, I've tried `LIKE` for the search, `[[:<:]]` `[[:>:]]` to set the word boundary, and `%` as wildcards for the rest of the string... though this doesn't work.

```
Post.where("title LIKE :keyword", {keyword: "%[[:<:]]#{keyword}[[:>:]]%"})
```

For reference I'm on ruby 2.1, rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word boundaries are part of regular expressions, which SQL doesn't have by default.  You need to add regular expression support in order to do what you're trying to do (see [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query) for details).

Also, to use regular expressions once you've added support for that, replace "LIKE" with "REGEXP" - you don't use "LIKE" with regular expressions.