# SQL LIKE to find either -,/,_

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard, sql-like

Trying to select from table where the format can be either 1/2/2014, 1-2-2014 or 1_2_2014 in a text field. There's other text involved outside of this format but it shouldn't matter, but that's why this is text not a date type.

I tried `'%[-,_,/]%[-,_,/]%'` which doesn't work, and I've tried escaping the special characters in the brackets such as `%[-,!_,/]%[-,!_,/]%' ESCAPE '!'` which also doesn't work. Any suggestions?

I wanted to avoid using three searches like,

```
LIKE '%/%/%'
OR '%-%-%'
OR '%!_%!_%' ESCAPE '!'
```

EDIT: Using SQLite3

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You may have to use `REGEX` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: Depending on what database you're using there are usually regular expression versions of LIKE available.  MySQL has `RLIKE`, Oracle has `REGEXP_LIKE`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no regex like behavior in using the `LIKE` operator in SQL. You would have use two expressions and `OR` them together:

```
select * from table
 where column like '%-%-%'
    or column like '%/%/%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information. I ended up switching to the GLOB operator which support [] in SQLite.

The Example was altered to GLOB '*?[/-_]*?[/-_]??*' Where * serves as % and ? serves as _ for the GLOB function.

Also thanks to Amadeaus9 for pointing out minimum characters between delimiters so that '//' isn't a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using T-SQL (AKA SQL Server) you don't want to have commas in the character set - i.e. `LIKE '%[/_-]%[/_-]%'`. However, keep in mind that this can match ANYTHING that has, anywhere within it, any two characters from the set.

EDIT: it doesn't looke like SQLite supports that sort of use of its LIKE operator, based on [this link.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm) 
Relevant quote:

```
There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:
The percent sign (%)
The underscore (_)
```

However, you may want to take a look at [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query) which details using regex in SQLite.

Comment: Doesn't work either, tried both with and without the wildcard _ ([/-] and [/-_]).

Comment: Edited to account for the use of SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using the LIKE syntax.

However Sqlite3 would support the REGEXP operator; this is syntactic sugar for calling an user defined function that actually does the matching. If provided by your platform, then you could use for example

```
x REGEXP '.*[/_-].*[/_-].*'
```