# SQLite: find records containing long string of numbers (without REGEXP)

Tags: regex, sqlite

Any way to use `WHERE`/`LIKE` in a SQLite query to find strings containing a bunch of numbers in a row?

I.e., the equivalent of REGEX `\d{10,30}`

(My implementation of sqlite does NOT support REGEXP.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: I tried that but got `Error: no such function: regexp` ... I'm on OSX, apparently this sqlite does not support that.