# Find a strict string in a field

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, search

I have a database, which contains a field 'topic'. This field is a short text, about 200-300 words, I would say.

I need to find a string in this field, but in a particular way: the field must contains the string as specified. It can't be a substring of another word. Such things as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE abstract like '%myString%"
```

Are not possible, because it would also return something+my_string+something.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE abstract like '_myString_"
```

Does not work either, because my field could start with myString, and it would not match.

I would love to use REGEXP, but sqlite doesn't seem to support it yet.
I read it is possible to tweak it, and use a personal function, but I would need a way to implement it for PyQt, to use it in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select records in whose `abstract` your string `'myString'` appears as a word delimited by spaces and/or either end of the string.  You say otherwise -- "only the string, and nothing else" to quote you -- but if that were indeed the case then obviously `WHERE abstract = 'myString'` would suffice; hence my inference that you're after something else despite what you say.

So, if I've read your mind correctly, then

```
WHERE ' ' || abstract || ' ' LIKE '% myString %'
```

would do the job -- bypassing your worry that "my field could start with myString, and it would not match" by concatenating spaces before and after the actual `abstract`.

Maybe you're after something more, e.g words in your abstract can also be delimited by (for example) commas; in that case,

```
' ' || replace(abstract, ',', ' ') || ' ' LIKE '% myString %'
```

would do the trick.  Of course, if there are too many possible punctuation characters that you want to tread this way, this gets cumbersome due to a "cascade" of `replace`, and that's where the craving for regular expressions gets fierce.  And in that case it *is* indeed possible to augment sqlite with a regexp library (depending on what platform you're on: I don't see what PyQt has to do with the issue), but it can be messy.  See [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query) if that's really the only avenue you can pursue... though Python may make it easier, e.g:

```
import sqlite3
import re

def resub(pat, sub, s):
return re.sub(pat, sub, s)

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.create_function("resub", 3, resub)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select resub('[,!?]',' ', 'O Romeo, Romeo, wherefore art thou Romeo?')")
print cur.fetchone()[0]
```

displays `"O Romeo  Romeo  wherefore art thou Romeo "` as desired... so maybe it's not quite as messy as with other non-Python uses of sqlite!-)

Comment: You nailed it, thanks. Actually, your answer gave me leads to solve my issue. I created a field abstract_simple (a sluggified version of abstract), and added a blank space at the beginning and at the end. Then I can use '% myString %' with no risk. And you also solve another issue, for the 'authors' field :)

Comment: @Rififi, always glad to be of help!