# SQLite - Extracting a single word in a text field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database filled with pure texts. I want a query to find some similar words to a specific sub-word. something like suggesting or guessing.

```
this is a database filled with data.
```

The sub-word I am looking for is `da`.

Now the result of the query should be only a column of single words like:

```
database
data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find rows that match 'da'. You could use something like `LIKE '%da%'` or `REGEXP 'da'` (see [this SO answer to know how to install REGEXP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338515/3673)).

Then you should extract **the word** corresponding to your pattern 'da'. That's where SQLite falls short of direct solution. In other DBMS, you have functions like `substring(string from pattern)` (for example [in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)). You don't have that kind of function in SQLite.

You could develop such a function on the same basis as functions in this [extension-functions.c](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib//download/extension-functions.c?get=25) file in the [contribs](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib/) or [this regexp operator for SQLite](https://github.com/eatnumber1/sqlite-regexp). But here you don't need the operator but the function that returns the match. I haven't found an existing extension for that.

Maybe you could use [SQLite Full-Text Search extension](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_8_2) tokenizers to extract the words you want.