# SQLite - How to use regex with if-condition?

Tags: regex, sqlite, if-statement

How can I use regex with if-condition in sqlite? My query below,

```
....
WHERE DATE(localdate) BETWEEN '2014-10-09' AND '2015-05-12'
AND n.nid = '9'

AND CASE WHEN '9' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN w.wspdi != '-9999' ELSE w.wspdi != NULL END
```

error,

> no such function: REGEXP

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: take a look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8338515/129283