# Extract string from a text after a keyword

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to extract content from text in an SQL field after a keyword. I have a field called `Description` in a table, the content for that field is:

> asdasf keyword dog
>
> aeee keyword cat
>
> ffffaa keyword wolf

I want to extract and save the text after "keyword " (in this case `dog`,`cat` and `wolf`) and save it in a view or show it with select.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://www.ashleyit.com/blogs/brentashley/2013/11/27/using-regular-expressions-with-sqlite/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is an example using `SUBSTRING()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourField, CHARINDEX(Keyword,YourField) + LEN(Keyword), LEN(YourField))
```

Another example:

```
declare @YourField varchar(200) = 'Mary had a little lamb'
declare @Keyword varchar(200) = 'had'
select SUBSTRING(@YourField,charindex(@Keyword,@YourField) + LEN(@Keyword), LEN(@YourField) )
```

Result:

```
 a little lamb
```

Please note that there is a space before the 'a' in this string.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(YourField, INSTR(Keyword,YourField) + LENGTH(Keyword), LENGTH(YourField)) for the mysql folks out there.

Comment: This solution gets all characters/words after the keyword. So if there are words after the `Dog` or `Cat`, that will be gotten to...not just the following word.

Comment: can you please provide the query equivalent in oracle SQL?

Comment: Equivalent for this in Oracle SQL please?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @psoshmo's answer
If keyword is not found it will substring the original string, to counter this I have added a case like below

```
SUBSTRING(YourField, CHARINDEX('Keyword',YourField) + (CASE WHEN ', ' + YourField +',' LIKE '%Keyword%' THEN LEN('Keyword') ELSE 1 END), LEN(YourField))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('Keyword', ColumnName), LEN(ColumnName)) FROM TableName
```