# From string, extract a word starting with a keyword (SQL or any other methods?)

Tags: mysql, sql, string, mariadb

Let's say I have a string of random characters, and I want to extract only the string that starts after a specific keyword (including the keyword). How could I do so using MySQL or MariaDB? ..............

String example:

> axds**SSF**ddlwie ====> **SSF**ddlwie
>
> aldfklafnlana**SSF**iiie ====> **SSF**iiie
>
> iii**SSF**nnnn ====> **SSF**nnnn

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853466/extract-string-from-a-text-after-a-keyword-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the base string functions we can try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, INSTR('SSF', col))
FROM yourTable;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is another option:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'SSF.*')
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
select concat('SSF', substring_index(col, 'SSF', -1))
```