# Replace instances of strings with NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database.  One of the columns has mostly integer values (either positive or negative).  In a few cases, the value is "not found" or "missing" or other text strings.

I want to replace all those non-integer values with NULL.  The column type is TEXT out of an original necessity.

Is there a clever way to do that with a UPDATE...WHERE clause instead of something gross, like pulling it into python to correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UPDATE` with regex, like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET text_column = NULL
WHERE text_column REGEXP '[^-0-9]+'
```

This would clear out all fields that contain one or more non-digit character.

Comment: I would also suggest changing the type of the column to a number after doing this.

Comment: REGEXP is not implemented by default.

Comment: Yeah, this looked like a slick solution until I discovered REGEXP is not a default function.  Haven't found clear instructions on how to install it so that I can use call it from the command-shell as well as access through my python scripts.

Comment: @user3556757 [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5071601/335858) shows how to do it on a UNIX machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can update all rows where the value cannot be converted into an integer:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = NULL
WHERE CAST(MyColumn AS INTEGER) != MyColumn;
```