# Adding a custom sqlite function to a Qt application

Tags: qt, sqlite

I am trying to add a custom sqlite3 `regexp` function into my Qt application (as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338515/1447002)). But as soon as I call the `sqlite3_create_function` function, I get the message `The program has unexpectedly finished.` When I debug, it terminates in a segmentation fault in `sqlite3_mutex_enter`. There is a MWE below, with apologies for the absolute file paths.

The `regexp` implementation in my code is from [this site](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48969-How-to-create-a-custom-function-in-a-QSqlDatabase-regex-in-sqlite-and-pyqt); it also fails with the `msign` function [here](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html). The various checks of `driver()->handle()` are straight from the Qt docs.

Incidentally, I used `select sqlite_version();` to determine that Qt 5.5 uses sqlite version 3.8.8.2. I found [that version](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/611bcc3cd337fe77ea5d3b898d897582da6f7ee2/src/3rdparty/sqlite) by looking through old commits in the Qt GitHub repository.

MWE.pro

```
QT       += core gui
TARGET = MWE
TEMPLATE = app
QT += sql
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    D:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\Src\3rdparty\sqlite\sqlite3.c

HEADERS  += D:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\Src\3rdparty\sqlite\sqlite3.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtSql>

#include "D:/Qt/Qt5.5.0/5.5/Src/3rdparty/sqlite/sqlite3.h"

void qtregexp(sqlite3_context* ctx, int argc, sqlite3_value** argv)
{
    QRegExp regex;
    QString str1((const char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]));
    QString str2((const char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[1]));

    regex.setPattern(str1);
    regex.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    bool b = str2.contains(regex);

    if (b)
    {
        sqlite3_result_int(ctx, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_result_int(ctx, 0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("my.db");
    db.open();

    QVariant v = db.driver()->handle();
    if (v.isValid() && qstrcmp(v.typeName(), "sqlite3*")==0) {
        sqlite3 *db_handle = *static_cast<sqlite3 **>(v.data());
        if (db_handle != 0) { // check that it is not NULL
            // This shows that the database handle is generally valid:
            qDebug() << sqlite3_db_filename(db_handle, "main");
            sqlite3_create_function(db_handle, "regexp", 2, SQLITE_UTF8 | SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC, NULL, &qtregexp, NULL, NULL);
            qDebug() << "This won't be reached."

            QSqlQuery query;
            query.prepare("select regexp('p$','tap');");
            query.exec();
            query.next();
            qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();
        }
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `sqlite3_initialize()` after you get the database handle from Qt, [according to this forum post](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/bug-causing-sigsegv-td24587.html).

```
    ...
    sqlite3 *db_handle = *static_cast<sqlite3 **>(v.data());
    if (db_handle != 0) { // check that it is not NULL
        sqlite3_initialize();
    ...
```

This solves the issue.

Comment: The referenced link is dead. Is there any chance this answer could be made self-contained?

Comment: The link was just giving credit. You can add this line inside the if-loop (`if (db_handle != 0)`) in the code in the OP.