# Adding a custom sqlite function to a Qt application in linux

Tags: qt, sqlite

I am trying to add a custom sqlite3 regexp function into my Qt application (as recommended by  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415351/adding-a-custom-sqlite-function-to-a-qt-application)). it works fine in windows but in fedora i get this error:

> :-1: error: sqlite3.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

after adding `LIBS += -ldl` to `.pro`, compile is ok but when run command  `query.exec();` return value is `false` without any description and `qtregexp()` function don't run.

***Edit:***

after comment

```
LIBS += -ldl
SOURCES +=  sqlite\sqlite3.c
HEADERS  += sqlite\sqlite3.h
```

and add

`LIBS += -lsqlite3`
to `.pro` i get `segmentation fault` with `sqlite3_create_function` .

if i open a database with native sqlite3 API (***sqlite3_open***) Instead handle of ***QSqlDatabase*** , sqlite3_create_function works very well

Comment: Does your code try to retrieve the error message?

Comment: hi CL, output of `db.lastError().text()`  is " ".