# Adding a custom sqlite function to a Qt application in wondows

Tags: windows, qt, sqlite

I am trying to add a custom sqlite3 regexp function into my Qt application (as recommended by this [Adding a custom sqlite function to a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415351/adding-a-custom-sqlite-function-to-a-qt-application) answer).

```
   QT       += core gui
   TARGET = MWE
   TEMPLATE = app
   QT += sql
   SOURCES += main.cpp \
      D:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\Src\3rdparty\sqlite\sqlite3.c
   HEADERS  += D:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\Src\3rdparty\sqlite\sqlite3.h
```

This method works, but I need to be independent of the qt installation path.

Comment: After compiling and deploying, you will no longer need the .h and the .c.

Comment: I want to move the source, not exe

Comment: then copy the 3rdparty directory to your project

Comment: hello @eyllanesc and thanks. i need to be  independent of the qt version.The program hangs by copying 3rdparty to my project in other versions of qt .

Comment: you have to use the version of sqlite3 that each version of Qt uses since sqlite3 changes from version to version as Qt does.