# How to create an SQL Function in QSqlDatabase?

Tags: sqlite, qt

How to create an **SQL Function** in **QSqlDatabase** ? The method, described in [Adding a custom sqlite function to a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415351) it doesn't work. When **sqlite3_create_function** is called, the program crashes, although there is a call to **sqlite3_initialize**. **QSqlDatabase** uses C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlited.dll, and **sqlite3_create_function** is called from sqlite3.c, added to the project. I added sqlite3.c because the linker does not find **sqlite3_create_function**

Comment: I have never done what you are trying but I do raise the same concern about `sqlite3.c` and `qsqlited.dll`