# How do I use regular expressions to parse text within SQL commands in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, regex, sqlite

How do I search for a certain text pattern in column data when coding in python using the sqlite3 package?

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query) interesting.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean that you can access MySQL with a sqllite3 module? This is new to me

Comment: for example, I want to look for transactions of a certain month in a table, which has a 'transaction date' column but not in standard format.So, you could have transactions for month of May looking anything like one of these:  08-May-2015 or 08May15 or 05-08-2015 or may 08, 2015. So, I want to write a regular expression that has 'May' or 'may' in it with possibility of characters before and after. then using the 'execute' command of sqlite3 package, using 'SELECT' in SQL, only select those entries that have transaction date in May. .... I hope that helps explain what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: @Pullie: Yes! .... do something like this: 
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('aDB.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\'') #list all tables in the database
print c.fetchall()
c.execute('SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\' AND name=\'sales\'') #list columns in table 'sales'
print c.fetchall()
conn.close()

Comment: Why are dates allowed to be used in different formats? It would be easier to only allow dates to be one format.

Comment: Are you asking someone to tell you how to write the regex to match those date formats, or are you asking someone to tell you how to use the re function?

Comment: @Rumbles: The latter. ... with the execute command, I don't know how to place a regular expression inside the SQL select command so that it would be interpreted as a RegEx and not taken literally!

Comment: I suggest you change your tags to show the right db

Answer (score 0):

From this question [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)

SQLite3 supports the REGEXP operator:

```
WHERE x REGEXP <regex>
```

Comment: If you felt that a previous answer in its entirety fully answers this question, flagging this as a duplicate might be a better approach than replicating content without bringing anything new on the table.

Comment: I already did that, I realised as soon as I posted :)