# Can I find all values LIKE ["_bc","a_c","ab_"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Just usuing SQLlite3 can I find the values that are LIKE what I am looking for and pass in an array?

e.g. I'd like something of the sort

`Url.where("token LIKE ?" ["_bc","a_b","ab_"])`

Comment: Don't forget you can [use regular expressions in SQLlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query).

Comment: Looks like you have to install a special package. Not a big deal but I am trying to solve it with just out the box SQLlite. For no good reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'll have to repeat the `LIKE` clauses for each of the condition, something like this:

```
like_conditions = %w(_bc a_b ab_)
Url.where((["token LIKE ?"] * like_conditions).join(" OR "), *like_conditions)
# => SELECT `urls`.* FROM `urls` WHERE (token like '_bc' OR token like 'a_b' OR token like 'ab_')
```

The first part of the `where` clause constructs an array of `token LIKE ?` strings with the same length as the number of like conditions and joins them using `OR` (change this to `AND`s if you need an `AND`ed query instead).

The last part just passes the conditions but not as an array but as the individual elements instead (that's what the `*` does) because the query now has three parameters instead of one.

Comment: OK. Seems reasonable

Answer (score 1):

You could try somehting like this (untested for SQLite):

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_tokens, lambda{|*tokens|
    query = tokens.length.times.map{"token LIKE ?"}.join(" OR ")
    where(query, *tokens)
  }
end

Url.with_tokens("_bc", "a_b", "ab_")
```