# SQLite multiple conditions in WHERE LIKE

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Is there anyway to have multiple conditions in a WHERE x LIKE %x% statement without using OR?

Basically I want to be able to select something where column1 LIKE %something% AND column2 LIKE %check1% OR %check2% OR %check3%

However, using OR removes my first previous check for column1 but I need this to stay in place

Here is what I'm currently using.. but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this so I don't have to keep repeating column1

```
SELECT id FROM test WHERE 
column1 LIKE '%bob%' AND column2 LIKE '%something%' 
OR column1 LIKE '%bob%' AND column2 LIKE '%somethingdifferent%' 
OR column1 LIKE '%bob%' AND column2 LIKE '%somethingdifferent2%'
```

Basically.. right now I keep having to repeat

```
column1 LIKE %bob%' AND .........
```

Just wondering if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you have against `OR` exactly? `select id from test where column1 like '%bob' and (column2 like '%something%' or column2 like '%somethingelse'% or column2 like '%morestuff%')` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT id FROM test WHERE 
column1 LIKE '%bob%' AND
    (column2 LIKE '%something%' OR
     column2 LIKE '%somethingdifferent%' OR
     column2 LIKE '%somethingdifferent2%')
```

It's logically equivalent...

You can also use a RegEx: see [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)

Comment: Yes, parentheses are the way to go! And it's a good idea to have them anyway when you start mixing `and` and `or`. Better to be explicit than relying on everybody remembering the priority between operators.

Comment: using parentheses didn't even come to mind! thank you