# JDBC SQLiteException - REGEX Function not found

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (SUBSTR (column_name, 18, 23) REGEXP '^some_text_[0-9]')";
Connection connection = SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection.getConnection();
 ResultSet currentResult = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

I am using  REGEX in my query . But the query is not executed . Throws exception

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: REGEXP)

But I'm able execute the query using other softwares like SQLitespy and in php. Also I'm able to use other functions like "LIKE","SUB STRING". But when I use regex function in java , it's throwing error. Is that regex not supported by jdbc ?

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?  If you're using a version earlier than 3 you might have to load your own user defined function.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query