# How to quickly filter a list using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Well... I have a trivial request of building an Entry that filter on-the-fly a list of entries. (think of an editor auto-complete feature)

The request is to support a regex filter over the whole list and display only matching entries.

e.g.,

The list contains:

```
abc.efg.hij.entry
abc.ddd.hij.entry2
hij.some.value.entry
```

Typing in the Entry

```
Value    :  List
hij      :  abc.efg.hij.entry, abc.ddd.hij.entry2, hij.some.value.entry
ddd      :  abc.ddd.hij.entry2
dd*entry :  abc.ddd.hij.entry2
val      :  hij.some.value.entry
```

Here is the code i'm using for filtering the list:

```
regex = re.compile(r"{0}".format(entry_value), re.IGNORECASE)
display_list = list(filter(regex.search, display_list))
```

The real life list contains ~300K entries of strings (up to 100 char each) and the performance of the above is very poor, considering a GUI response time.
I've profiled my real test case and it yields ~0.8s for each key typing in the Entry.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing regular expression pattern matching against a normal python list that contains 300,000 items, it's just naturally going to be slow. Also, if you are going to display 300,000 items in a listbox it's going to be slow to display all of those items.

Your best bet might be to pick a better data structure. For example, on my system I can run your filter against 300,000 items in about 250ms, but a query against an in-memory sqlite database with 300,000 rows takes about half that time.  In either case, it can add another second to fully update the display if the result is very large (for example, if all 300,000 match)

Of course, sqlite doesn't support regex out of the box, but you can translate some common patterns to sql patterns (eg: 'foo.*bar' could be translated to 'foo%bar'). For more information on sqlite and regex see [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5071601/7432)

Another strategy to employ would be to not search on every character typed. Wait until the user pauses in their typing. So, for example, if they type "Lorem", you don't need to search on "L" and then "Lo", and then "Lor", etc. Instead, schedule the search to happen in 100 ms, and with each keypress you can reschedule the search. This will prevent the searching from slowing down, while still giving the user what appears to be a fairly rapid result.

Comment: Thanks - excellent tip - i moved my in-memory database to sqlite3 - filter time dropped to below 100ms (x8 optimization). As of the listbox itself, this is already optimized (i'm showing only a small portion of the filtered list, and let the user browse through it...)