# sqlite valid email input

Tags: regex, sqlite

I am trying to make a databank in SQLite 3.19 that checks if the inputed value is a valid one.
My problem is checking if an email is really an email address.

I tried to put a regex like:
    `CHECK (x REGEXP '[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}')`

It throws "no such function: REGEXP".

Is there any easy way to implement REGEXP into sqlite 3.19?
Is there maybe any other, nice way to check for email addresses?

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query