# SQLite - Get records which is not start with alphabet - IOS - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

IOS - Objective C - SQLite Query.

I want records from user table which is name start with a special character or digit or else (Not start with alphabet a-z or A-Z).

If i have tried like following query then i got a result which is name start with 'a'.

```
  char ch = 'a';
    
  NSLog(@"%@",[db writeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from user where first_name like '%c%%'",ch]]);
```

If have tried following query, But got app crash.

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[db writeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from user where first_name REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]'"]]);
```

Got error like follow.

> SQLite Prepare Failed: no such function: REGEXP
>
> - Query: SELECT * from user where first_name REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]'

Comment: use ***where*** on your query,  the query as like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name REGEXP`

Comment: for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEXP is [not available by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query); you'd have to add your own implementation for it to work.

You can get this to work with [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) instead:

```
... WHERE first_name GLOB '[^a-zA-Z]*'
```