# Select only values that start with an uppercase letter in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a column `name`. The values in this column can be capitalized or not (e.g. both "adam" and "Adam"). How can I select only values that are capitalized (start with an uppercase letter)?

Comment: What version of SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQLite3, you can employ the `REGEXP` expression

```
WHERE name REGEXP '^[A-Z]'
```

There's some good information in this answer regarding installation ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338515/283366

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit with `collate binary` and a comparison:

```
where name collate binary = 'Adam' collate binary
```

However, `binary` is often the default so it is probably not necessary.

If you mean *any* capitalized letter, then:

```
where substr(name, 1, 1) collate binary = 'A' collate binary
```

Comment: Whilst required, I don't think this answers the question of *"How can I select only values that are capitalized (start with an uppercase letter)?"*

Comment: @Phil . . . I see what you mean.  Your interpretation makes more sense.

Comment: I want to search all names, and the names in the column don't just start with A, it can be any letter.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way of doing it using REGEX:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'your_table'
WHERE 'field' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]'
```

Comment: Are those the right quotes to use for table / column names?

Comment: Of course you'll use the other quotes (I didn't use them here cause they're interpreted as a code sample :)

Comment: You can use graves / backticks in code samples. SQLite also supports square-bracket identifiers