# Ignore HTML tags and search text only in SQLite

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I am making an android app that displays stored HTML data using webview. Now, the problem I am trying to over come is how to ignore HTML/CSS etc tag/elements when searching for some user-input string. My DB is already 110MB and I think using another field with only text and no HTML will just add more size to DB. Regex will be expensive too and may not be reliable.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do an additional filtering in your program on the queried records. You can use HTML parsers like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to strip HTML tags, then you can search in the remaining text. Simple Java example with Jsoup:

```
List<String> records = ... // your queried records - potential results
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String r : records) {
    Document d = Jsoup.parse(r); // parse HTML
    String text = d.text(); // extract text
    if (text.contains(searchTerm)) { // or do your search here
        results.add(r);
    }
}
return results; // you got real results here
```

It may not be the best solution but is an option. I think it's expensive too, but more reliable than regular expressions (which you try to avoid).

**Update: the regex way**

I think the only way to strip HTML tags while fetching is to use [regex in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query). For example, the following pattern should work to match string outside HTML tags:

```
(^|>)[^<]*(searchterm)[^<]*(<|$)
```

In the following example text it will match only the 1st, 3rd and 4th `searchterm` and not the 2nd:

```
searchterm <tag searchterm> searchterm </tag> searchterm
```

You can see it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/ep9WMu3rOg).

In SQLite you can use regular expressions this way:

```
WHERE column-name REGEXP 'regular-expression'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. There is no way to do the filtering when I am fetching records from DB? e.g where column-name like user-string? Fetching all data from DB and the processing that is going to slow down the search process.

Comment: That would be the regex way, I can't think of any other solution. I added example to my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if anyone here can suggest better way. Then I will weight your solution against having extra column with plain text and querying that directly. 

Thank you, Juzraai