# Sqlite3 select between from not standart date format

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with `Date` column with type `DATE` where values is looks like: `'%d.%m.%Y'`. How I can get rows for current month? I already tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE Date BETWEEN strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date('now','start of month')) AND
    strftime('%d.%m.%Y', date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day'))
```

But then I get all rows. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: SQLite has no formal date type, and as a result dates are stored as plain text.  This being the case, _it is critical_ that you store your text dates in an ISO format.  This means a format like `%Y.%m.%d`, i.e. year, month, day.  Your current date format will make _every_ query a real headache.  I could give you a workaround, but that would just be feeding a beast.  Fix your date data.

Comment: You must change the date format to %Y.%m.%d or use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query).