# SQLite3 Full text search using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 to track daily tests of my system , I logged all failure test ID lists/P4 Change List/Error info , etc in my SQLite3 DB below :
[image]

Here is what I am trying to do with SQLite3 module **in Python** 
I want to use regular expression to search for any test parameter "combo" in "Failure Tests List" column.
Let's say , I want to filter all failure tests contains "-algo5" and "-P2"
If I use SQLite command :

> "select * from Table where Failure_Test_List **have** "algo5" and
>   Failure_Test_List **have** "-P2";"

it will treat Failure Tests List as a "WHOLE" rather than several different Test items.

So I am thinking of using Python "regex" module to handle it , is it possible ? Or any other SQLite **embedded command** / module I didn't realized ?

> [Modified to point out difference between my problem and the "dup"
>   question]

One more thing I'd like to point out is , the test items in "Failure Tests List" are actually combination of **multiple tests**, when dealing with them using **REGEXP** (at least this is the tool I think of for now, maybe there is another tool fit more) , sqlite command will treat them as a **WHOLE** any tools in sqlite can split them into separate tests items and use regex to filter each one of them , and then list out those matches ?

Comment: try checking this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: I tried "REGEXP" with my sqlite3 , it reports error below:  

sqlite> SELECT suite FROM test where Failure REGEXP '*algo5*';
Error: no such function: REGEXP

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions, you have to use the [ICU](https://www3.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?ci=1e29fd430dead641&name=ext/icu) module or a third-party module that provides them.

Comment: @Wiltor Stribizew