# CHECK constraint failed

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like, glob

I'm using sqlite3

I have created a table of a class like this

```
CREATE TABLE Class (
    ClassID char(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (ClassID LIKE 'CT[1-9][A-Z]' OR 'AT[1-9][1-9][A-Z]'),
    ClassQuantity int NOT NULL CHECK (ClassQuantity > 0)
);
```

And when I insert some values to this table

```
INSERT INTO Class
VALUES ('CT2D', 50);
```

It shows me an error message

> 'CHECK constraint failed'.

I have written the values based on the condition in the check. Can someone help me with this problem.

Comment: Are you using SQLite or SQL Server?

Comment: Please edit your question and tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIKE` expression in your check constraint is trying to use the extended syntax supported by databases like SQL Server and Sybase.  However, I don't think this syntax is supported by SQLite.  As a workaround, if your version of SQLite has `REGEXP`, we can use that instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Class (
    ClassID char(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (ClassID REGEXP 'CT[1-9][A-Z]|AT[1-9][1-9][A-Z]'),
    ClassQuantity int NOT NULL CHECK (ClassQuantity > 0)
);
```

Comment: Oh yes, I see! I'm used to SQL Server and I thought it is supported for sqlite3 but i'm wrong! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Huy Vũ: And if `REGEXP` is not available, you can revert to mere string functions (`classid LIKE 'CT%' AND LENGTH(classid) = 4 AND SUBSTR(classid, 3, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' AND ...) OR (classid LIKE 'AT%' AND ...)`).

Comment: @HuyVũ So you're using SQL Server not SQLite?

Comment: I'm currently learning SQL Server @Sami but my project requires SQLite

Comment: @metal [SQLite 3 supports REGEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query).

Answer (score 4):

You miss to write the `OR` condition there `OR ClassID LIKE 'AT[1-9][1-9][A-Z]'`

```
CREATE TABLE Class (
  ClassID char(5) PRIMARY KEY 
  CHECK (ClassID LIKE 'CT[1-9][A-Z]' OR ClassID LIKE 'AT[1-9][1-9][A-Z]'),
    ClassQuantity int NOT NULL CHECK (ClassQuantity > 0)
);

INSERT INTO Class
VALUES ('CT2D', 50);
```

Comment: SQLite does not support this `LIKE` syntax, [see this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=79ee7c342bc75855ba62c12d61f48327).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The question was tagged with SQL Server tag. You can see the revision.

Comment: The question begins with `I'm using sqlite3` ... I would assume this to be the case, unless the OP doesn't even know its own database.

Comment: @Huy Vũ: As you see, by originally tagging several irrelevant DBMS you have made Sami put in effort in vain. Please refrain from tagging your requests with moot tags in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use `GLOB()`. as mentioned [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

```
CREATE TABLE Class (
  ClassID char(5) PRIMARY KEY 
  CHECK (ClassID GLOB 'CT[1-9][A-Z]' OR ClassID GLOB 'AT[1-9][1-9][A-Z]'),
    ClassQuantity int NOT NULL CHECK (ClassQuantity > 0)
);

INSERT INTO Class
VALUES ('CT2D', 50);
```

sqlite [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=z6lBgqvKKg)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know of the `GLOB` operator. This is the perfect solution for this check constraint in SQLite.