# Regex in sqlite

Tags: regex, sqlite

i have been thinking about this a lot.

So i wanna create a table which contains a password.
The password should at least be 6 chars long a contain minimum 2 numbers.

My version was:

```
create table User (
  passwort varchar(80) not null check (length(passwort) >= 6 and passwort like '%[0-9]%[0-9]%')
);
```

The Problem with this approach is that the password has to contain [0-9] twice instead of the actual numbers. Does anyone know how to get rid of that problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried \d?

Comment: What if you use this pattern: `^.*?\d.*?\d.*?$` and then check the length of the string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)

Comment: SQLite does not support regular expressions with the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 0):

How about `.*?\d.*?\d.*?`

This ensures that between zero or more characters (including digits), there must be 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

While I still recommend you split the work in 2 as per my comment, ie.

1. Check the length of the string.
2. Use the actual expression to check if the string contains 2 numbers.

You can use the following expression: `^(?=.{6,}).*?\d.*?\d.*?$`. What is does is that it *looks ahead* for a minimum of 6 characters and then checks that the string is made up from 2 numbers, which can be separated by 0 or more characters.

An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/PAbGxO/1).

Comment: i just tried your suggested pattern but unfortunately, that does not work too.

Comment: @PersianAssassin: Do you have any examples wherein my answer fails please?