# How can I search a regular expression with an inverted pattern using SQLite?

Tags: regex, sqlite

I know that in order for using a regular expression with SQLite, I need to install a module for regular expressions as [described on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338515/14739472).

However, even though the query

```
select * 
from mytable 
WHERE mycolumn is not NULL and mycolumn regexp('^Word.*$')
```

works fine, if I try to use:

```
select * 
from mytable 
WHERE mycolumn is not NULL and mycolumn is not regexp('^Word.*$')
```

I receive an error telling me:

> wrong number of arguments to function regexp().

What am I missing? Is it a syntax error?

Or should I take a different approach to get the inverted pattern of a regular expression on SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement:

```
... and mycolumn regexp('^Word.*$')
```

maybe you think that you are using the function `regexp()`, but actually you are using the [`regexp`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp) operator and the expression is interpreted as:

```
... and mycolumn REGEXP '^Word.*$'
```

So, the correct way to implement the inverted pattern is:

```
... and NOT (mycolumn REGEXP '^Word.*$')
```

or:

```
... and mycolumn NOT REGEXP '^Word.*$'
```

Note that you could use the `regexp()` function, but with arguments in the opposite order of the `regexp` operator:

```
... and regexp('^Word.*$', mycolumn)
```

and for the inverted pattern:

```
... and not regexp('^Word.*$', mycolumn)
```