# Why the fuzzy matching using [] doesn't work in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named emp like this:

[image]

And I want to get the enames which start with 'A' or 'B'. So I write the query like this:

```sql
select ename from emp where ename like '[AB]%'
```

But it return nothing instead of 'ALLEN' or 'BLAKE'. So I changed the query into:

```sql
select ename from emp where ename REGEXP '[AB]%'
```

But it still didn't work and said there is no such function name REGEXP. Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link may help you when using REGEXP. Sqlite3 supports REGEXP only

[How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)

However, I think the solution can be like this and no regex is need to be used:

```
select ename from emp where ename like 'A%' or ename like 'B%'
```

Comment: Does MySQL suppport using `where ename like '[AB]%'` directly?

Comment: @Chor No, you have to define the function, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it as a user-defined function.
It would be simpler to just rewrite your query without regex. I.e.

```
select ename from emp where ename like 'A%' or ename like 'B%'
```