# SQLite regex - not PCRE? What are the rules?

Tags: regex, sqlite

I'm pretty used to the PCRE regex flavor at this point, and some other alternatives like plain `grep`'s style. But, I couldn't figure out how to do some basic things in the new built-in SQLite regexes (version 3.37.2)

Attempting to match a whole string with `^` and `$` anchors works as expected:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '^pancakes$';
1
```

I'd expect this next one to work. I always thought `|` had "everything to left" and "everything to right" behavior (low "precedence"?):

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '^pan|cakes$';
0
```

That works fine in Python:

```
>>> re.search(r"^pan|cakes$", "pancakes")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='pan'>
```

Maybe I have to escape `|`? But doesn't work:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '^pan\|cakes$';
0
```

Does `|` work at all? Yes, it seems to, but maybe not doing what I think:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP 'pan|cakes';
1
```

Maybe the precedence is off, I'll group to be safe. Uh oh:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '(^pan)|(cakes$)';
Error: stepping, unmatched '(' (1)
```

(escaping the parens also gave the same error)

How can I do grouping, anchoring, `|` etc? I wasn't able to find much about the regex style in the docs, just something saying that `REGEXP` operator is really using some regex function under the hood.

Comment: SQLite supports different implementations of the regular expression parser. You may optionally install a PCRE-compatible implementation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338515/20860

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin. That install might be the way to go. Do you know what the default implementation is called, if not PCRE? Do other languages/tools share that implementation, or do you know of a guide on how to write regular expressions in that style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the code for the default regexp implementation: https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/regexp.c

The syntax documented in a code comment block suggests that the syntax you used should work, but I find it does not. I tested on 3.37.0 and then upgraded to 3.39.3 but it still fails.

I was able to get it to work this way:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '(^pan)|cakes$';
1
```

It seems in the SQLite regex parser, `|` binds tighter than `^` or `$`, so without the parentheses, it evaluates as if we had written it this way:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '^(pan|cakes)$';
0
```

This is obviously not going to match, because it would only match the whole string "pan" or "cakes".

This is not compatible with PCRE semantics.

I also tried to use explicit parentheses to override the precedence of `|`:

```
sqlite> SELECT 'pancakes' REGEXP '(^pan)|(cakes$)';
Runtime error: unmatched '('
```

This should work, but it hits a bug in SQLite with respect to `^` and `$`. Read these threads for the discussion from July 2022:

- https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/96692f8ba5
- https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/18f87fdcdf